# Avro java.io.EOFException when using transform in a KStream DSL

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams

I need to use the transform() operation in a KStream but am getting the usual ClassNotFoundException that happens when not setting the necessary serdes:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: xxx.SomeKey cannot be cast to [B
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer.serialize(ByteArraySerializer.java:21)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:161)
```

```
val someKeySerde = SpecificAvroSerde<SomeKeySerde>()
someKeySerde.configure(serdeConfig, false)
val someValueSerde = SpecificAvroSerde<SomeValueSerde>()
someValueSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false)
val someExtendedValueSerde = SpecificAvroSerde<SomeExtendedValueSerde>()
someExtendedValueSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false)

myKStream
    .transform(TransformerSupplier {
        object : Transformer<SomeKey, SomeValue, KeyValue<SomeKey, SomeValue>> {

            private lateinit var context: ProcessorContext

            override fun close() {
            }

            override fun transform(key: SomeKey, value: SomeValue): KeyValue<SomeKey, SomeValue> {
                println("@@@@@@@@@@@@ timestamp ${context.timestamp()}")
                ...   
                return KeyValue(key, enrichedValue)
            }

            override fun init(context: ProcessorContext) {
                this.context = context
            }

        }
    }).groupByKey()
      .aggregate(getSomeValueAggregationInitializer(),
                        getAggregator("absolute"),
                        materializedAbsoluteSomeValueFrequency)
```

Other KStream operations allow us to specify the serdes to use, but not in the case of transform. How can I set them? (as you can see above, the SpecificAvroSerde) ?

**UPDATE:** As pointed out by Matthias the problem is the lack of Serdes in the groupByKey operation that followed the transform. I've updated the question title with the new problem.

**1) Why does it work without `Grouped.with(clientProjectIdSerde, deploymentFinishedSerde)` when there isn't a transform() call but I need to add it after transform()?**

If I update the groupById to include the GroupedWith -> `.groupByKey(Grouped.with(clientProjectIdSerde, deploymentFinishedSerde))` now I can see the call logs `("@@@@@@@@@@@@ ...` but a new problem arises:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id -1
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id -1
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.ensureBounds(BinaryDecoder.java:473)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readLong(BinaryDecoder.java:160)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readLong(ResolvingDecoder.java:162)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:184)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readField(SpecificDatumReader.java:116)
```

If I leave exactly the same code without the `.transform()` it works:

```
myKStream
    .groupByKey(Grouped.with(clientProjectIdSerde, deploymentFinishedSerde))
      .aggregate(getSomeValueAggregationInitializer(),
                        getAggregator("absolute"),
                        materializedAbsoluteSomeValueFrequency)
```

**2) Why am I getting this Avro exception with the transform() but not without it and how can I fix it?**

The error happens when reading the dateTime long field from the SomeValue Avro object:

```
{
  "namespace" : "xxx",
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "SomeValue",
  "fields" : [
    {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
    {"name":"dateTime", "type": "long", "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: are you sure the ClassCastException is thrown by the transformer you copied/pasted, and not in the code after (or before) the transform?  I ask this, because the exception is about an issue with  SomeKey , but in your code you do not touch the key part of the message: you accept a SomeKey in and you send out a SomeKey....

Comment: If I remove the transform() call the rest of the process works fine so it seems to come from it.

Comment: It's unclear from the code, but the exception can only occur if some data is written into some topic. Do you have a consecutive `to()` operation after `transform()`, or do you uses a state store within `transform()` that may write into a changelog topic?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I've updated the question with new info, thanks for having a look at it

Comment: If you set Serdes upstream, Kafka Stream tries to use them downstream is key and value type does not change. However, if you use `transform()` both key and value type may change and hence, it's unsafe to use upstream Serdes. Therefore, Kafka Streams falls back to the default Serdes from the config if you don't set the Serdes again.

Comment: Can it be that you have some corrupted data in some topic? Try to reset the application to get rid of all stale data.https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I have identified the problem, the error didn't happen when using a "normal" Kafka broker, only during tests. In these I rely on `io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.MockSchemaRegistryClient` where I think there's a bug. I'll give details in the answer. Could you have a look at it and tell me if I'm right to open a github PR with the solution?

Comment: Finally no need for the PR, 5.2.2 solved it :-)

Answer (score 1):

**The answer to the 1st question** was provided by Matthias in the comments.

Regarding the second one, the actual scenario in which the problem showed up was during tests. Against a normal Kafka Broker + Schema Registry it worked fine.

The problem was in the `io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.MockSchemaRegistryClient` class that I used during testing.

This is the flow of schema registrations:

1) First it read a record from the input topic and registered a schema for SomeKey with id 1 and SomeValue with id 2.

2) After `transform()` the process logic uses a repartition topic. It tries to serialize the key. For this the `MockSchemaRegistryClient.getIdFromRegistry()` method generated a wrong id (-1) for the schema of the key and the value. Then when it tried to serialize the key it used the -1 id which had been first assigned to the key but later overriden to the value schema. Thus, it was trying to serialize the key with the schema of the value. That was the reason of the Avro exception.

I was using io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-client:5.2.1. Upgrading to 5.2.2 the problem disappeared. This is the commit of the fix: https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/commit/6ef5d4a523a5eedff0fa32bea1e1405be42efc13#diff-e5caaf947bc9ff275003783d5d50eee6R90